# C++ linux библиотека libcurl

Tags: g++, c++, linux

С++ приложение под linux с использованием библиотеки libcurl. На машине установлен пакет libcurl4-openssl-dev, все компилируется и работает.
Компилирую командой: 
`g++ test.cpp -lcurl -o test`
проверяю зависимости: 
`ldd test
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0x0000003ff3400000)`

могу ли я взять этот libcurl.so.4 из системной директории /usr/lib и таскать вместе с программой? Если да то как прилинковать его на этапе сборки?
Возможно у кого то есть реальный пример статической или динамической сборки приложения с libcurl.
Спасибо!

Comment: не нужно брать библиотеку для распространения. Так делают только в виндах. В линуксе просто указываете, что Ваша программа зависит от этой библиотеки. Если соберете как пакет, то система даже сама доустановит все, что нужно. Если Вы распространяете бинарником, то просто уточните, что нужна библиотека.

Comment: @KoVadim уважаю ортодоксов. Но если пользователю неудобно устанавливать в системе это dll'ю? 

@arhon смотрите примеры использования переменной LD_PRELOAD.

     LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/curl/libcurl.so.4 BinOfYourGreatProgramm

Comment: @alexlz какая DLL в Linux? С другой стороны, 'приехав в Рим, будь римлянином' - перейдя в Linux, живи по его правилам - будет проще.

В большинства пользователей эта so скорее всего уже есть:)

Comment: @KoVadim

    какая DLL в Linux?

Ну поскольку про a.out вспоминать не стоит совсем, то elf-овская .so

А правила... Ну приютил кто-то бедолагу (хостинг называется), а curl'ов нетути. И ставить не хотит... Куды бедному крестьянину податься?

Comment: @KoVadim 
Согласен с вами, но обычно клиенту не хочется заморачиваться и доустанавливать дополнительные библиотеки. Например под RedHat libcurl из репозитория не установить, только rpm пакетом, что опять таки не очень удобно.
@alexlz
Спасибо за наводку. Поясните пожалуйста: допустим я собираю приложение g++ test.cpp -lcurl -o test, перед его запуском на сторонней ОС я просто указываю где хранится моя библиотека LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/curl/libcurl.so.4 и все? Система сама поймет что предопределенная зависимость -lcurl есть в моей директории?

Comment: @arhon могу наврать, лучше почитайте про dynamic link libraries. При линковке в код бинарника включается stub (пень?) из libcurl.a, который и обеспечивает вызов функций из libcurl.so. Т.е. код для вызова функций из libcurl.so уже находится в Вашем бинарнике. Нужна только сама .so (если она в системе есть и зарегистрирована

А LD_PRELOAD немного круче. Даже если в системе (ld.conf) зарегистрирована такая библиотека, для данного бинарника будет использоваться указанная в LD_PRELOAD. Так что возможно лучше установить LD_LIBRARY_PATH (см. man ld.so)

Comment: Так просто утащить библиотеку не получиться. Ведь эта библиотека может быть зависимой ещё от нескольких (посмотрел на своей машине, кстати, на ней федора, что почти redhat - так оно и есть - libcrypto, libssl и много других - всего 33 штуки). Не будете же Вы тянуть все либы?

LD_PRELOAD - это для особых случаев. Для отладки, для вредных программ, типа скайпа.

Answer (score 1):

> могу ли я взять этот libcurl.so.4 из системной директории /usr/lib и таскать вместе с программой?

да, можете, конечно.

вот только смысла в этом действии, как верно подсказывают в комментариях, — чуть.

если требуется «самое надёжное решение», то можно «таскать с собой» *usb-storage* (aka «флэшку») с *live*-системой, в которой установлено всё, что необходимо, включая вашу программу.